# Is this an appropriate use of temptables?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a data set that looks a lot like this:

```
TrxDate     DayOfWk TrxHour TrxName Succeeded
Oct 21 2012 Sunday  0       signon  1
Oct 21 2012 Sunday  0       Bal     1
Oct 21 2012 Sunday  0       Bal     1
Oct 21 2012 Sunday  0       hist    1
Oct 21 2012 Sunday  0       Bal     1
```

In reality, I need to use an `INNER JOIN` to get on a uniqueID to get the result-set looking like this, but that's something of a detail.  The requirements I have been given are:

- Group based on the date, the day of the week, and the hour of the day.
- Output the number of successful sign-ons for each group.
- Output the number of unsuccessful sign-ons for each group.
- Output the total number of sign-ons for each group (successful + unsuccessful).
- Output the total number of transactions for each group (essentially, `Count(UniqueId)`).

So the output should look like this:

```
Date        Day of Week Hour    Login Success   Login Failures  Total Logins    Total Transactions
11/15/2012  5           22      12,000          1,000           13,000          25,000 
11/15/2012  5           23      15,223          1,500           16,723          33,000 
11/16/2012  6           0       22,000          3,000           25,000          12,554 
11/16/2012  6           1       18,000          2,000           20,000          15,899
```

Obviously, minor stylistic differences on how `Date` and `DayOfWk` are presented.  They're not important.

**Problem:** I don't see a better way to do this than to dump everything from the `INNER JOIN` into a temptable and run extended queries to catalog that temptable in the various ways the result set requires.  The `INNER JOIN` touches two tables with hundreds of thousands of rows.  This technique is slow, speed-wise, and bloaty, memory-wise.  This solution will work, but I'd like to take a bit more pride in my work than that!  Does anyone have any ideas for accomplishing this a bit more gracefully?

I have taken a big crack at the answer below.  My query now looks like this:

```
SELECT
LEFT(first.EntryDateTime, 11) AS [Date]
,DATENAME(weekday, first.EntryDateTime) AS [Day of Week]
,DATEPART(hh, first.EntryDateTime) AS [Hour]
,SUM(CASE WHEN second.TrxName = 'signon' AND first.Succeeded = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Login Success]
,SUM(CASE WHEN second.TrxName = 'signon' AND first.Succeeded = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS [Login Failure]
,SUM(CASE WHEN second.TrxName = 'signon' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Total Logins]
,COUNT(first.UniqueId) AS [Total Transactions]

FROM
dbo.TheFirstPlace first (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN
dbo.TheSecondPlace second (NOLOCK)
ON  first.TrxUniqueId = second.TrxUniqueId
WHERE first.EntryDateTime > DATEADD(day, -7, cast(GETDATE() As Date))
GROUP BY
    LEFT(first.EntryDateTime, 11),
    DATENAME(weekday, first.EntryDateTime),
    DATEPART(hh, first.EntryDateTime)
```

And my result set looks like this:

```
Date        Day of Week Hour    Login Success   Login Failure   Total Logins    Total Transactions
Nov  9 2012 Friday      0       554             26245           595             26799
Nov  9 2012 Friday      1       2113            120569          2509            122682
Nov  9 2012 Friday      2       1675            102058          1743            103733
```

Obviously, the math here doesn't work at all, and I'm confused as hell as to why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could probably make a single pass at the data if you used a combination of `CASE` and `SUM` statements.  This will likely be more efficient that doing multiple `COUNT` queries... something like the following:

```
SELECT
    [Date],
    [Day of Week],
    [Hour],
    SUM(CASE WHEN TrxName = 'signon' AND Succeeded = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Login Success],
    SUM(CASE WHEN TrxName = 'signon' AND Succeeded = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Login Failure],
    SUM(CASE WHEN TrxName = 'signon' 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Total Logins],
    COUNT(UniqueId) AS [Total Transactions]
FROM
    YourTable
GROUP BY
    [Date],
    [Day of Week],
    [Hour]
```

Comment: But, just to clarify, you don't see a way for me to avoid using the temptable altogether?  If not that's fine, this answer already rules, I just want to be sure.

Comment: @YYY one way to get rid of the temp table is to replace the `FROM YourTable` in the code above with your `FROM table1 JOIN table2 ...`.

Comment: @YYY Like w0lf says, if you end up only needing to make one pass at the data, I don't think the temp table buys you anything, and you can just combine the query that populates the temp table with this query that aggregates the data.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I wasn't thinking clearly enough to notice that.  I will give this a shot, thank you very much!

Comment: Hey Michael, the `CASE WHEN` clauses are behaving extremely oddly and I have absolutely no idea what is going the heck on.  I am updating my question with the new information.  I'd appreciate it if you could give me any insight.

Comment: @YYY I think I see the issue.  The login failure total was including events that were not logins.  The updated query should give better results.

Comment: Aaagh, now that you mention it it's obvious to me, too.  Thanks for all your help!